# Asmack not loading VCard

Tags: android, vcf-vcard, asmack

I am using a binary release of Asmack (I will be building it as soon as I have some time as I had problems the first time I tried). I also set up my own ejabberd server.

When I try to load some contact VCard the server returns the info but Asmack does not seem to like it (or fail to parse it).

This is what I can see in debug mode:

```
<iq from='user@domain' to='admin@domain/Smack' id='I17sI-4' type='result'>
<vCard xmlns='vcard-temp' prodid='-//HandGen//NONSGML vGen v1.0//EN' version='2.0'>
    <FN>Full Name</FN>
    <N>
        <FAMILY>Surname</FAMILY>
        <GIVEN>Nick</GIVEN>
    </N>
    <NICKNAME>Nickname</NICKNAME>
    <URL>http://google.com</URL>
    <ADR>
        <LOCALITY>lanta</LOCALITY>
        <REGION>krabi</REGION>
        <PCODE>81150</PCODE>
        <CTRY>thailand</CTRY>
    </ADR>
    <EMAIL>
        <USERID>user@domain.com</USERID>
    </EMAIL>
</vCard>
</iq>
```

But when I do

```
VCard card = new VCard();
card.load(xmppConn, "user@domain");
```

All the info is set to null, and when I try to look at the XML by calling VCard.toXML() method I just got an empty XML like this

```
<iq id="I17sI-4" to="user@domain" type="get"><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq>
```

So anyone knows what I am doing wrong or if this binary release that fails to parse the VCard received from the server?

Comment: try this:
   `ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());` 
should work for regular smack, not sure about asmack...

Comment: Thanks Maggie! Inserting that line before trying to load the vCard solved the issue ;-)

Comment: I will write it as an answer, so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add line: `ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());` before loading vCard.

Comment: please help me for getting vcard

Comment: @SubbaReddyPolamReddy what is the problem?

Comment: @Maggie can you tell me why `<iqProvider>
        <elementName>vCard</elementName>
        <namespace>vcard-temp</namespace>
<className>org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.VCardProvider</className> </iqProvider>` not working in smack.provider