# asmack - can't read VCard

Tags: java, android, smack, vcf-vcard, asmack

I did exactly what the answer suggested ( [Asmack not loading VCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355684/asmack-not-loading-vcard) ) but it still doesn't work. The DEBUG output shows that Smack receives the packet with the VCard information but then throws a ClassCastException in https://github.com/rtreffer/smack/blob/master/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/packet/VCard.java#L548 and all I get is 'No VCard for xxx@xxx'.

My code:

```
public VCard getUserVCard() throws XMPPException {
    VCard userVCard = new VCard();
    userVCard.load(connection);
    return userVCard;
}
```

And some previous initialization:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(OF_HOST, OF_PORT, OF_SERVICE_NAME);
config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard ", "vcard-temp", new org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.VCardProvider());
connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
this.context = context;
try {
    connection.connect();
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The VCard information in the database is OK - only the final casting fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: One comment - if I use the VCardProvider directly, I am able to create a VCard from a String:

`String vCardString = prefs .getString(UserPreferences.USER_VCARD, null);
  userVCard = VCardProvider.createVCardFromXML(vCardString);
`

Comment: Have you tried using the other method `userVCard.load(connection, user);`, user being the id of the user you want to retrieve the vCard (i.e. your id in this case)? I don't know if it will work better but that's the one I'm using with success.

Comment: I tried that as well and the result was similar. The VCard data is fetched from the server but it is not parsed as a VCard object by asmack.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this. I am not able to parse any users' VCard although they are fetched from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided not only to add the VCardProvider but the whole nine yards in the configuration following this post [getSearchForm returns null when using UserSearch in XMPP with aSmack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910219/problem-using-usersearch-in-xmpp-with-asmack) and it worked.